# Excluir registros separados por vírgula

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo o upload de várias imagens e ao guarda-las no banco, até aí está perfeito. Os registros são gravados, separados por vírgula no campo `materialDocumento` na tabela `tb_material`.
O problema é que não estou conseguindo excluir uma imagem em específico que seja selecionada, quando necessário.
Poderiam me ajudar?

Os arquivos são registrados no banco da seguinte forma:

```
498818_03c4414ce0324292a51e63009f513a82_mv2.jpg, 64223640_2226772990741441_1192728863528976384_o.jpg, 64254162_1912126265586260_4480819099357675520_o.jpg, 25044125149117.jpg
```

material-edita.php

```
<a href="material-edita.php?edita_material_ID=<?php echo $_GET['edita_material_ID']; ?>&imagem_material=<?php echo $img; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" name="btn-deletar-imagem"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> &nbsp; Excluir Imagem Material</button></a>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['edita_material_ID'])) {
      $materialID = $_GET['edita_material_ID'];
      extract($classeMaterial->getID($materialID));

      $mDocumento = $_GET['imagem_material'];

  if ($classeMaterial->deletarArqImg($materialID, $mDocumento)) {
    var_dump($mDocumento);
  }
}
?>
```

class.classe_material.php

```
<?php
    public function deletarArqImg($materialID, $mDocumento) 
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_material WHERE materialID = :materialID AND materialDocumento = :mDocumento");
            $stmt->bindparam(":mDocumento", $mDocumento);
            $stmt->bindparam(":materialID", $materialID);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Se quer apenas excluir uma imagem específico, não faz muito sentido dar `DELETE` no registro inteiro. Não seria melhor fazer um `UPDATE` removendo a imagem da lista?

Comment: O mais simples seria gravar cada imagem com um id, agora estando elas juntas você terá que recuperar o registro, e separar com um explode, o que vai gerar um array e depois encontrar o índice respectivo... Ou seja, repense a forma de salvar as imagens...

Comment: Sim Anderson, concordo. Mas quando dou UPDATE, ele deleta todos os registros e acrescenta o registro que eu queria deletar. Acredito que o explode poderia resolver como comentou o MagicHat. Poderia me dar uma orientação de como faze-lo?

Comment: Fabio, a solução com explode irá lhe dar muito mais dor de cabeça do que remodelar essa seção em sua base de dados. Se esta mexendo nisso, refaça, perca um pouco mais de tempo. Crie uma tabela só para as imagens, cada imagem com um id e associe com o id do material.

Comment: Justamente, já que está usando um banco relacional, não tem porque se beneficiar dele para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você estava armazenando uma "coleção" de valores em string você precisa entender o que está fazendo.

Todos os seus documentos relacionados a um determinado material estão salvos como um único valor (string). Então o seu banco de dados não entende que existem vários documentos relacionados pois não foi realizado essa estrutura. Mas como você sabe que existem várias relações o ideal é seguir a sugestão do [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) e realizar um `update` na string.

---

Primeiro, é necessário obter o registro a ser atualizado (Caso não tenha um método para isso):

```
public function find($id)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_materia WHERE materialID = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $material = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $material[0];
}
```

---

Após obter o registro pelo `id`, é necessário verificar se o documento a ser excluído existe para então realizar o `update` no lugar do `delete`.

```
public function deletarArqImg($materialID, $mDocumento) 
{
    $material = $this->find($materialID);

    //Utilizar o array_map para aplicar a função trim (remover os espaços vazios do lado direito e esquerdo) em cada valor do array
    $documentos = array_map('trim', explode(',', $material['materialDocumento']));

    $key = array_search($mDocumento, $documentos); //Verificar se existe o documento a ser "excluído"
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($documentos[$key]); //Removendo o documento do array de documentos
        $newDocumentos = implode(',', $documentos);

        try {
            $update = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_material SET materialDocumento = :newDocumentos WHERE materialID = :materialID");
            $update->bindParam(":newDocumentos", $newDocumentos);
            $update->bindParam(":materialID", $materialID);    
            return $update->execute(); //Retorna TRUE para sucesso ou FALSE para falha
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é seguro fazer `if ($key)` para validar o retorno de `array_search`, pois o valor procurado pode ser o primeiro do *array* e ser retornado o índice 0, não entrando no `if`. O ideal é fazer `if ($key !== false)` dado que o retorno é `false` quando o valor não é encontrado. Ou usando as condições Yoda: `if (false !== $key)`.

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss pelo observação, agora nunca mais esqueço isso xD

Comment: O grande problema é como informar a posição correta a ser substituída, como a aplicação vai identificar o registro a ser excluído? Pode ser o índice 0, hora o índice 2 e assim por diante... Cada imagem tem de ter o próprio identificador.

Comment: O correto seria desta forma mesmo, obdecendo a estrutura *one to many* mas para o caso que ele informou não tem muito o que fazer. Ele pode fazer a solução que postei ou reestruturar essa parte na base de dados como você havia sugerido.

Comment: Esta me aparecendo o seguinte erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$material' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in classes\classe_material\class.classe_material.php on line 158

Comment: @Fabio, atualizei a resposta com a correção. A instrução `explode` precisa de dois parâmetros separados por vírgula, estava sendo passado os dois parâmetros mas sem a separação.

Comment: Perfeito Victor. Entendi, funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado. Agradeço imensamente pela ajuda. E eu concordo com os colegas, o melhor e mais fácil procedimento seria criar uma tabela a parte. Mas o problema e alterar toda a estrutura do projeto e acrescentar mais um JOIN nas minhas QUERY´S, o qual já estão  bem grandes pela quantidade de tabelas relacionadas que tenho. Mas a ajuda de vocês foi fantástica e agradeço a todos pela ajuda.